# How can I get the id of a list item at specific index from a list in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to retrieve the id of the list item that is next to the list item being clicked.
For example, consider the following list. Now, when 'item 1' is clicked, I need to retrieve the id of 'item 2'.

```
<ul>
<li id="id1">item 1</li>
<li id="id2">item 2</li>
<li id="id3">item 3</li>
</ul>
```

All these id's are dynamic. I am able to get the next list item using the following code:

```
$li = $('li').get(ui.item.index() + 1);
```

But when I try to get it's id by using the following code, it doesn't work.

```
$nextid = $li.id;
```

Or

```
$nextid = $li.attr('id');
```

I would really appreciate if anybody can help me with this issue or suggest any alternate solution!

Comment: What should the result be if someone clicks the last `<li>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `next()` function:

---

**UPDATE #1**

Check the second evant listener. Every time you click on the button, a random number from 1 to 6 is generated. Use this number to get the list element with this index (minus 1, because index is zero based).

---

**UPADATE #2**

Updated the first function so that when user clicks the last list element, the id of the **first** list element will be alerted, as David Thomas mentioned.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
  var nextID;
  var nextElem = $(this).next(); 
  if (nextElem.length > 0) {
     nextID = nextElem.attr('id');
  } else {
     nextID = $(this).closest('ul').children('li').eq(0).attr('id');
  }     
  alert(nextID);
});

$(document).on('click', '#random', function() {
   var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
   var elem = $('ul').find('li').eq(index - 1);
   alert(elem.attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id="id1">item 1</li>
<li id="id2">item 2</li>
<li id="id3">item 3</li>
<li id="id4">item 4</li>
<li id="id5">item 5</li>
<li id="id6">item 6</li>
</ul>

<button id="random">Get random id</button>
```

Comment: @kapantzak: Thanks! It is working. Is there any way I can get id of a random list item from it's index when any list item is clicked?

Comment: why use var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;? This is static and it is not good... use var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('li').length) + 1; instead.